# Evitar login automático después de crear usuario en Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5, laravel

¿Como evitar que después de registrar un usuario este inicie sesión automáticamente en laravel 5.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tendrías que hacer un override del método `register()` del trait `RegisterUsers`, probablemente en el controlador `RegisterController`.

El código original es:

```
/**
 * Handle a registration request for the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    $this->guard()->login($user);

    return $this->registered($request, $user)
        ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

La parte que te interesa y que seguramente quieres eliminar (comentar) o modificar es:

```
    $this->guard()->login($user);

    return $this->registered($request, $user)
        ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
```

Comment: Creo que no entendí bien la funcionalidad del metodo, le quite la propiedad [->login($user] y redirigí hacia una ruta distinta [return redirect('user/gtest');]  pero no funciono, le puse la propiedad protected al metodo al sobreescribirlo y me sale este error [FatalErrorException in RegisterController.php line 44:Multiple access type modifiers are not allowed] y cuando no le pongo [protected] al metodo sale este error: [ReflectionException in Route.php line 339:
Class App\Http\Controllers\TestauthAuth\Request does not exist]

Comment: Debe mantenerse public el método. Te falta agregar el namespace del Request: `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar, ahora me da este error `FatalThrowableError in RegisterController.php line 50:Class 'App\Http\Controllers\TestauthAuth\Registered' not found`

Comment: Mi función register quedo de esta forma: `public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

        $this->guard();

        return redirect('user/gtest');
    }` estoy trabajando con un modelo diferente al `user` que viene por defecto.

Comment: `use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;`

Comment: Muchas gracias @Shaz ha funcionado correctamente.

Comment: Con gusto. Si la respuesta te sirvió, puedes considerar aceptarla.

Answer (score 2):

En Laravel 5.4 se soluciona buscando el archivo: RegistersUsers.php en la carpeta de su proyecto, luego van al metodo register

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    $this->guard()->login($user);

    return $this->registered($request, $user)
                    ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```